# Existe alguma forma de forçar uma opção de um <mat-option> por um service?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Basicamente tenho um `mat-option`, e gostaria de selecionar uma opção dele diretamente por parâmetros, com um service, por exemplo.

Este é o option:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="form.get('emptyTitle')" placeholder="Nenhum Índice Selecionado">
   <mat-option value="">Nenhum Índice Selecionado</mat-option>
   <div *ngFor="let indice of indices">
       <mat-option (click)="selectionClick()" [value]="indice._id">{{indice._source.titulo}}</mat-option>
   </div>
</mat-select>
```

Quando eu carrego esse componente ele está sem nenhuma opção marcada, porém existe uma funcionalidade que necessita que uma opção deste `mat-option` seja selecionada, via parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Basta vc ter o form control com o mesmo valor que o value do seu option. Por Exemplo:

```
this.form.get('emptyTitle').setValue(this.indices[0]._id)
```